# How to send email after 2 days without CRON job?

Tags: magento, cron, magento-1.7

Is there any way to send email after 2 days without using cron ? Maybe there is some often using observer event or something like that ?

Comment: Can you explain the situation for which you want to send email after two days?

Answer (score 0):

The sleep command will do this if you have a command line way to send email.

sleep 2d; (email command here)

more info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_(Unix)